# How to RSA encrypt in golang using encryption key from 3rd party API

Tags: go, encryption, cryptography, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I'm struggling to achieve encrypted password to utilize Ig.com Stock-trading API using encrypted passwords. All examples from `crypto/***` packages don't seem to fit IG.com's requirements.

**Their documentation states that following steps are required**:

1. call /session/encryptionKey which gives a key and timestamp
2. create a RSA token using the key.
3. encrypt password + "|" + timestamp

Calling https://demo-api.ig.com/gateway/deal/session/encryptionKey provides following type response: (*part of the response replaced with asterisk*[*]):

```
{
    "encryptionKey": "**************iG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAo8GLjXQTT96zXJI0Nvhuw8vpGrtB7x0qErBwCXm15x5xnsiZzKyhWy3tyn6Tpe+Yyiaz+gbqBFUChVQ/Plm7ntKepcI68rUnqW1OKFOTP4oZJnu7bs8l0etqeJwIG87pqsnn6CAkWg6BIMBT7QShQj71HBJ8JXiOcm2plc5wXxlO8dD5TN+a3bytf9OMUxZn9ggzauI4RiU0ElybxoeayTbqSrGQkg/D01G3PuDjQa5yf3I5WHSYS+BpylfupsfurbO/ugCmsGVugV5ST7VLK7TReVWxjg20P+/LSJ1gkoVxHIMzmN0I4jk2N2/667nSzmkCZSb4jTyOjdcOlCgWyw******",
    "timeStamp": 1598268011542
}
```

My attempted solution is as following:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    encryptionKey := "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAo8GLjXEYY96zXJI0Nvhuw8vpGrtB7x0qErBwCXm15x5xnsiZzKiuWy3tyn6Tpe+Yyiaz+gbqBFUChVQ/Plm7ntKepcI68rUnqW1OKFOTP4oZJnu7bs8l0etqeJwIG87pqsnn6CAkWg6BIMBT7QShQj71HBJ8JXiOcm2plc5wXxlO8dD5TN+a3bytf9OMUxZn9ggzauI4RiU0ElybxoeayTbqSrGQkg/D01G3PuDjQa5yf3I5WHSYS+BpylfupsfurbO/ugCmsGVugV5ST7VLK7TReVWxjg20P+/LSJ1gkoVxHIMzmN0I4jk2N2/667nSzmkSDSb4jTyOjdcOlCgWywIDOITT"
    timestamp := 1598300292178
    rawPassword := "testpassword123"

    encryptedPassword, err := EncryptPassword(encryptionKey, rawPassword, timestamp)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("Error occurred, while encrypting the password. Error:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Encrypted password:", encryptedPassword)
    fmt.Println("")
}

func EncryptPassword(encryptionKey, rawPassword string, ts int) (string, error) {
    bytes, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encryptionKey)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error encoding the string to binary array: ", err)
        return "", err
    }

    key, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(bytes)
    var pubkey *rsa.PublicKey
    pubkey = key.(*rsa.PublicKey)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while generating the key:", err)
        return "", err
    }

    var passwd string
    passwd = rawPassword + "|" + strconv.Itoa(ts)

    encrypted_password, err := rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, pubkey, []byte(passwd))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while encrypting the password:", err)
        return "", err
    }

    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(encrypted_password), nil
}
```

EncryptPassword() gets called with encryption-key from `/session/encryptionKey` the `password + "|" + timestamp` as instructed.

It returns encrypted password of some sorts, but further calls to IG.COM API responds with **401 Unauthorized**:

```
{
    "errorCode": "error.security.invalid-details"
}
```

Example implementation in JavaScript: https://github.com/wagerfield/ig-api/blob/102d97647a13e921f473d8287fd17f896ce3fdf1/src/utils.js#L29

Comment: Is your password really base64 encoded? Even then, you shouldn't be ignoring the error returned by `base64.DecodeString`. Beyond that, you should at least point to the docs and show how you're concatenating the password with the timestamp.

Comment: As shown in working example [wagerfield/ig-api](https://github.com/wagerfield/ig-api/blob/102d97647a13e921f473d8287fd17f896ce3fdf1/src/utils.js#L29) it should be base64 encoded.

Comment: Not sure what you were trying to show, but the JS code just passes `${password}|${timeStamp}` to `publicEncrypt`, there's no encoding going on.

Comment: Yes, the output should be base64 encoded. But before calling `rsa.Encrypt`, you're base64 decoding the `rawPassword` parameter and not even checking the error. You're likely encrypting an empty slice of bytes.

Comment: That was correct, error checking gives: illegal base64 data at input byte 20

Comment: Ok, so now does it work? If not, you should show how you combine the password and timestamp. You should also check what padding the javascript example uses.

Comment: Javascript should use the same padding scheme as go (PKCS#1 v1.5), added dummy example on edited question. Encryption is not correct according to IG's API, but it encrypts the password and no error thrown.

Comment: @JoniKämppä, have you sorted out this issue as i have same issue in to IG password encryption?